# How to test `gets.chomp` with minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

My program asks for a new planet name, gets a response, and then prints a message that the planet has been created. Here is the Ruby code that does this:

```
puts "Explore strange new worlds"

class CreateWorld
  def initialize
    puts 'what is the name of your planet?'
    get_planet_name
    new_planet_greeting
  end
  def get_planet_name
    @name = gets.chomp
  end
  def new_planet_greeting
    @name = @name.capitalize
    puts "\n hi there I like the name of your planet, it's groovy baby \n"
    puts "\n \"#{@name}\" will be a great addition to the universe \n"
    puts "\n notifying all federations and starships about the creation of \"Planet #{@name}\""
  end
end

myWorld = CreateWorld.new
```

How do I test my code? I check for user input within the spec. Here is the minitest spec that tests the code:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'createworld.rb'

describe "CreateWorld" do
  before do
    @World = CreateWorld.new
  end
  it "gets planet name" do

  end
  it "returns a new planet confirmation greeting" do

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `gets` and `chomp` are built in Ruby methods, so I do not understand the point of testing those methods, but if you insist on doing so, then since they are called in `get_planet_name`, you probably want to test `get_planet_name`.